# deleting a project from workspace in Eclipse

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-neon

I'm running Eclipse Neon on Windows 7 64 bit, and I think I messed up.

I tried to install SWT to my Eclipse configuration. I installed the 64 bit SWT, but my Java VM is 32 bit, so it didn't work.

I tried to install the 32 bit instead, but since it was already installed, I couldn't select the checkbox (see image).

[image: SWT import problem]

Then I wanted to remove the 64 bit installation by deleting it from the workspace. It didn't remove the installation however, and I'm left here with no SWT.

What should I do? Reinstall Eclipse?

Comment: Try creating a new workspace(Option under File) before reinstallation.

Comment: Thanks, I did and it worked! Now, do I need to use the new workspace whenever I want to use SWT? Or should I migrate my stuff from there?

Comment: Update: I imported all my projects to this shiny new workspace, and I will continue to work with this one.